# $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-g(x))$ is an integral domain when $g(x)$ is of odd degree.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Show that $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-g(x))$ is an integral domain where $g(x)$ is an odd degree polynomial in $\mathbb C[x].$Construct an example of an even degree polynomial $g(x)$ such that $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-g(x))$ is an integral domain.

If we take $g(x)=x$ then we can say easily that $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x)$ is an integral domain as $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x)\cong\mathbb C[t]$.

So for $g(x)$ given as odd degree , should we take the transformation:$x\mapsto t^2, y\mapsto g(t)$. Then It becomes so difficult to show the kernel.

Comment: It won't always be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t]$.

Comment: Your suggestion won't work; for example, if $\deg g = 3$ it's already not isomorphic to a polynomial ring in one variable. You just need to show that $y^2-g(x)$ is irreducible. Since $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is a UFD, there's not many ways that it can factor.

Comment: @SteveD I also don't want to make $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-g(x))$ isomorphic to $\mathbb C[t]$. I was trying to find an integral domain which will be isomorphic to $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-g(x)).$

Comment: @JohnBrevik then where it is needed the degree of $g(x)?$

Comment: If $g$ has odd degree, you can show directly that $y^2-g(x)$ can't factor (how could it? see my above comment). If $g$ has even degree, it might or it might not -- _e.g._ $y^2-x^4$ does factor.

Comment: $\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-g(x))\simeq\mathbb C[x][\sqrt{g(x)}]$, and the last one is a subring of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb C(x)$.